# Potentially devious behaviour of pygments´ mapping.py / Editing a pygments lexer

Tags: python, pygments

I'm using Windows 7, latest windows update etc.

Recently I decided to start using the `minted` package in LaTeX. For this, I was redirected to install `pygments`, which I installed through `pip`:

I'll run you through quickly what I did (to make sure I didn't do anything wrong):

1. Installed python 3.4 from [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/).
2. `easy_install pip` in the windows command prompt.
3. `pip install pygments` in command prompt.
4. I've added the `%PYTHONPATH%` as well as `%PYTHONPATH%\Scripts` (which is where `pygments` operates from I've been led to believe), to the system PATH environment.

I'm typing source code from `R` into LaTeX, but the releases I could find do not offer the capital `R` syntax. If I use LaTeX code as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{R} % Capital R won't function as intended with recent release
c(1,2,5,7,8)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

It won't recognise the capital `R` argument in `minted`.

Now, the lower case `\begin{minted}{r}` works just fine, so I've looked around on how to fix this, and found [this answer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-03/msg00617.html).

Here it is suggested to adjust the `math.py` lexer (at `%PYTHONPATH%\Lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers`) to add an alias `'R'` to current aliases. It *also* suggests to run `_mapping.py` in the same directory (`%PYTHONPATH%\Lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers`). Running `_mapping.py` has two effects:

1. It completely empties the file, the file size is reduced to 0 bytes and editing it with IDLE confirms an empty file.
2. It also yields this error message.

*Not* running `_mapping.py` won't apply my new alias to `pygments`. Running it, breaks `pygments` entirely. The error code is shown below.

I ran the LaTeX code again (with changes and `_mapping.py` also run), with pdfLaTeX, with arguments: `$synctexoption`, `--enable-write18`, `-interaction=nonstopmode` and `$fullname` (also in this order), I get the following error in LaTeX:

```
LaTeX Error: File `temp.out.pyg' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: out.pyg)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.64 \end{minted}^^M
```

After running `_mapping.py` on a clean installation even (no changes made to any lexer or anything), I also run into the same problem. I'm uncertain whether the initial changes I made, changed registry values and whatnot, but I'm having serious issues applying this simple change to the `pygments` lexer.